# Hide App and Tabs in Professional Edition Salesforce

Tags: limits, professional-edition

Is there any way to hide tabs and App from the professional edition?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I have an one app that is build on other base app and now I want to hide all tabs from the base app as I only need the child app not base app

Comment: Are you asking how to remove particular tabs from a particular app, or how to hide the app picker and all tabs altogether?

Comment: I am asking to hide a particular tab from particular app.